# OkHttp3 cookie trouble on Sony Xperia Z5

Tags: android, cookies, retrofit, okhttp

I passed cookie in OkHttpClient Builder called this:

```
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager))
            .build();
```

Before, I create CookieManager by this code:

```
    CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
    manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
```

And the most devices recognize cookies and be authorized, but on SonyXperia Z5 cookies don't pass into my request!

I use OkHttp and OkHttp-UrlConnection 3.2.0.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

PS: I checked it on OkHttp 2 version -- same result.

Comment: Can you write a test case for CookieManager that fails on that device? You can use the CookieManager API directly; no need to actually make network calls.

Comment: @JesseWilson I haven't this device at hand. It's bug from crashlytics.

Comment: Does this occur on all SonyXperia Z5 devices? You could buy one!